# Filling webview form using textview android

Tags: android

Hey I am displaying a website using webview android, it asks for the userName and mobile then it has a submit button. I want to get the user details in my EditText box and then set it to the webview page using webViewClient in android java. Please help me I am unable to do it using javascript injection.

Comment: Could you please paste the code here that you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your response I have solved that, help me in this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210672/how-to-validate-the-digital-signature-using-cert-file-in-java