# How to verify the digital signature of downloaded xml file in java

Tags: java, cryptography, xml-signature

I have an XML file, given below

```
<OfflinePaperlessKyc referenceId="686820201209011401091">
<UidData>
<Poi dob="21-01-1945" e="bd05902a34b7b9e4d92230ac6b0asded072c1c0945190ad357f9ceec387f6fd6" gender="M" m="ed4eeb1376575c1b59096cf5c41243re5f3d4146e0c63eb4cc08a6c22fa9afe5" name="Reepak Sangid"/>
<Poa careof="S/O John Uncle" country="India" dist="Jaipur" house="1134 - B" landmark="80 Feet Road 200 Feet Baypass ke pass" loc="Heerapura Ajmer Road" pc="302024" po="" state="Kerala" street="Heera Nagar" subdist="" vtc="Jaipur"/>
</UidData>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>+ribhQOajFYDHgBTkjU0LSHWxRWpBkkrh4FbUj+RVss=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>qGxO1EURe+FOr0mBocWvBDGuZm3ssVu6dYwSs5IvuA2OhlqH+Cp2WSQ3OKFvLZPfVSXBDNy/zC2F M5NI7RJjl2KaCMX+Qhko7UTpQp/8a/gX3jjcRP5Az8w4GQONIuZhLjUXxqgA4ln0y8vqfEhqdtVk 407QopDyNx6UH9VFCgmGjcDggLUgam1gG4P8Hka3WxT0BFTL7CWO4yVPRwEs8IvhcNvm8Db7p50a qWMwfOmNQQ/G7uj+tQ2wEKzWPcBoeQ6/qGCGfN+1Wt0gmEWIxYaKEDz9kQb8eiYOQSaht+2QzOX7 68gMrDXSms6ljrcklqmVrXwKvJXe5L0tfbNBuA==</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
</OfflinePaperlessKyc>
```

Here some details about signature:

*signature - Signature: – This will a 344 character long digital signature of the data present in the downloaded XML. This can be validated using the public key of UIDAI which will be present in standard signed XML.*

Here are the steps provided by the website from which the XML is downloaded:
Steps to validate the signature :

1. Read the entire XML.
2. Get signature from XML
3. Get Certificate from [here](https://uidai.gov.in/images/authDoc/uidai_auth_sign_prod_2023.cer).
4. Convert the certificate to base64 string.
5. Sample code snippets provided [here](https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/developer-section/915-developer-section/tutorial-section.html).

Here is the text in the certificate file

```
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
```

How can I verify the digital signature provided in the XML file using the certificate file. I have searched many questions but they did not work for me. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I tried:

```
String certificate = "MIIG7jCCBdagAwIBAgIEAv5vUzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB4jELMAkGA1UEBhMCSU4xLTArBgNVBAoTJENhcHJpY29ybiBJZGVudGl0eSBTZXJ2aWNlcyBQdnQgTHRkLjEdMBsGA1UECxMUQ2VydGlmeWluZyBBdXRob3JpdHkxDzANBgNVBBETBjExMDA5MjEOMAwGA1UECBMFREVMSEkxJzAlBgNVBAkTHjE4LExBWE1JIE5BR0FSIERJU1RSSUNUIENFTlRFUjEfMB0GA1UEMxMWRzUsVklLQVMgREVFUCBCVUlMRElORzEaMBgGA1UEAxMRQ2Fwcmljb3JuIENBIDIwMTQwHhcNMjAwNTI3MDUwMzA1WhcNMjMwNTI3MDUwMzA1WjCCARAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQ4wDAYDVQQKEwVVSURBSTEaMBgGA1UECxMRVGVjaG5vbG9neSBDZW50cmUxDzANBgNVBBETBjU2MDA5MjESMBAGA1UECBMJS2FybmF0YWthMRIwEAYDVQQJEwliYW5nYWxvcmUxOzA5BgNVBDMTMlVJREFJIFRlY2ggQ2VudHJlLCBBYWRoYXIgQ29tcGxleCwgTlRJIExheW91dCwgVGF0MUkwRwYDVQQFE0BiMTlhODdmYWU3YWU5ZWY1NWZmMTY2YjVjYzYyNTcwMGUyOGQ4MmRhNzZiZDUzZjA5ODM2ZWVhZWFiM2ZlMzg1MRQwEgYDVQQDEwtEUyBVSURBSSAwMTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANSINogOm/Y3pyz0xqILE4C8eJ79af1dk9Kt0QWuICQyq2beNWzBFml5BVBLjeUvjbWbz2zv4yY9lotTb0kKlWEwP+yctIVVDliaWHr+/zxcwAFDoJKLULJokvIYaUeSDrLDvtSq2K3eypIvmS5Df/T6miBJKyYbxDj+8LTZxeSXh12xBUs9X6RxkWSM2cqIJkPPb2mPYFwchtTCczapaUYaGoQB6mbbwW1PQR6qXxUBVefFe373sGh3Pyty0bOOw/NBYHLES1p+3jUXSp2ovqMxsEEIq0c/oCjjhbJYUKa0190EhZDyTYojGuNsD4VCb7jJk1xN67szEKyYQ2Ld/40CAwEAAaOCAnkwggJ1MEAGA1UdJQQ5MDcGCisGAQQBgjcUAgIGCCsGAQUFBwMEBggrBgEFBQcDAgYKKwYBBAGCNwoDDAYJKoZIhvcvAQEFMBMGA1UdIwQMMAqACEOABKAHteDPMIGIBggrBgEFBQcBAQR8MHowLAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGIGh0dHA6Ly9vY3ZzLmNlcnRpZmljYXRlLmRpZ2l0YWwvMEoGCCsGAQUFBzAChj5odHRwczovL3d3dy5jZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZS5kaWdpdGFsL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvQ2Fwcmljb3JuQ0EyMDE0LmNlcjCB+AYDVR0gBIHwMIHtMFYGBmCCZGQCAzBMMEoGCCsGAQUFBwICMD4aPENsYXNzIDMgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUgaXNzdWVkIGJ5IENhcHJpY29ybiBDZXJ0aWZ5aW5nIEF1dGhvcml0eTBEBgZggmRkCgEwOjA4BggrBgEFBQcCAjAsGipPcmdhbml6YXRpb25hbCBEb2N1bWVudCBTaWduZXIgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwTQYHYIJkZAEKAjBCMEAGCCsGAQUFBwIBFjRodHRwczovL3d3dy5jZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZS5kaWdpdGFsL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvY3BzdjEucGRmMEQGA1UdHwQ9MDswOaA3oDWGM2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNlcnRpZmljYXRlLmRpZ2l0YWwvY3JsL0NhcHJpY29ybkNBLmNybDARBgNVHQ4ECgQITfksz0HaUFUwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgbAMCIGA1UdEQQbMBmBF2FudXAua3VtYXJAdWlkYWkubmV0LmluMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBACED9DwfU+qImzRkqc4FLN1ED4wgKXsvqwszJrvKKjwiQSxILTcapKPaTuW51HTlKOYUDmQH8MXGWLYjnyJDp/gpj6thcuwiXRFL87UarUMDd5A+dBn4UPkUSuThn+CjrhGQcStaKSz5QfzdOO/2fZeZgDB0xo7IyDtVfC2ZvW1xrxWngKNVkp8XkPNmPW/jHk7395/1obaHsjKNcAaAxNztXGG6azwsURx83Fy6irF4pHFTfZV3Y93iBZovXeetYc1bgIAvLSFd2Yvuy6yGyL8nb8vUMbWYIasZ47E4q+kMDmB49xedQg97L5CRfN0gIrk7foxnTexvSlLtEVo2M/A=";
            byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificate.getBytes());
            String signatureValue = "qGxO1EURe+FOr0mBocWvBDGuZm3ssVu6dYwSs5IvuA2OhlqH+Cp2WSQ3OKFvLZPfVSXBDNy/zC2F M5NI7RJjl2KaCMX+Qhko7UTpQp/8a/gX3jjcRP5Az8w4GQONIuZhLjUXxqgA4ln0y8vqfEhqdtVk 407QopDyNx6UH9VFCgmGjcDggLUgam1gG4P8Hka3WxT0BFTL7CWO4yVPRwEs8IvhcNvm8Db7p50a qWMwfOmNQQ/G7uj+tQ2wEKzWPcBoeQ6/qGCGfN+1Wt0gmEWIxYaKEDz9kQb8eiYOQSaht+2QzOX7 68gMrDXSms6ljrcklqmVrXwKvJXe5L0tfbNBuA==";
            byte[] aadharSignature = signatureValue.getBytes();

            //Creating KeyPair generator object
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGen.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair pair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privKey = pair.getPrivate();
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            signature.initSign(privKey);
            signature.update(aadharSignature);
            //Initializing the signature
            signature.initVerify(pair.getPublic());
            signature.update(decoded);

            //Verifying the signature
            boolean bool = signature.verify(decoded);

            if(bool) {
                System.out.println("Signature verified");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Signature failed");
            }
```

But this does not work and generates an error while generating the key.

Comment: There is no need to generate a new key pair on your side. You receive a XML-document with an embedded signature, the certificate is provided online and your "only task" is to verify the signature with the public key you directly get from the certificate.

Comment: please give an example, like just explain which one is key, use of certificate and verification process. Please help I got a lot of views in this question but no one answering.

Comment: Are you sure that this XML file can be verified with the certificate?Are the XML file and the certificate from the posted link? While the certificate can be loaded, the sample data cannot be accessed (Access denied / You don't have the user rights to view this page).

Comment: yes , the certificate is downloaded from the website

Comment: Your posted [link](https://uidai.gov.in/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/developer-section/915-developer-section/tutorial-section.html) does not work for the sample data. Where did you get the XML file and how do you know that it can be verified with the certificate? Did you perform the verification with the linked C# snippet?

Comment: https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offline-kyc

Comment: hey thanks for your time, I will find the answer and upload it